# Configure SAML SSO with azure ad b2c and ping one idp

Tags: azure, saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have an application that uses oauth to sign user in with my azure ad b2c tenant . Now i want that my app has a button that links the user to third party application from my website and i want to authenticate that user to third party application using SAML with my azure b2c tanent acting as idp and sending saml to third party on user's button click.

Is this scenario possible. ???

Comment: So basically you want a SSO from your application towards other third party? It is feasible (Third party needs SSO integration and on your side you will have to do redirection with a special token in some case), but I don't think you can authenticate to third party with that B2C SAML directly.

Comment: The third party has an sso application set up with sign on url, relay url and sassid on ping one. 
Why would not we be able to authenticate, do we need something extra also or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. What you mean is [SAML as RP](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Walkthroughs/RP-SAML.md). 
In SAML as RP case,

- B2C acts as IDP
- B2C accepts SAML requests
- B2C sends SAML assertions as output

I can help you if you stuck anywhere...

Comment: Hey! Thanks for sharing this link. Just have a doubt like: what would be the link or button which i will have to add in my application such that on clicking it my azure b2c tanent sends saml to third party and verifies it and allows user to log in directly

Comment: Hi , I followed the url but i am getting error when i click on the sso login url. It just shows exception occured and nothing else. Can you help ?

Comment: Yes, I can... what is the error message you are seeing on user journey?

Comment: Please open the following link , this is the page i am getting    https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/APHAxisMobile.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signinsaml/samlp/sso/login

Comment: Also, can you connect on skype or any other channel ?

Comment: Your Policy not properly configured. I can't see metadata of your policy at https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/APHAxisMobile.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signinsaml/Samlp/metadata . First you need to configure your policy properly. If you follow SAML RP link I shared above that will help you how to configure your policy properly. Regarding skype, I can but let me comeback to you on that.

Comment: Hi, Ramakrishna. We followed the document and created the policy and also I removed some unused UserJourney and related TechnicalProfile as I do not need that. But we are facing an error on login page. Base file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ro6arbs57c43el2/base.xml?dl=0   Extension file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqojtk432b3wny1/base_Extensions.xml?dl=0 SignInSamle file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/i950s4bwwagry5k/signinsaml.xml?dl=0

Comment: when you try metadata URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/example.onmicrosoft.com/{RPPolicyName}/Samlp/metadata, what are you getting on screen? from your give sample files your metadata URL will be: https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/example.onmicrosoft.com/signin/Samlp/metadata

Comment: follow https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%205.md and you can setup debugging mode of policy at userjourney recorder. But remember  Microsoft does not officially encourage this and you should use application insights to debug. I placed debugging link here as it is officially published on GitHub, they may revoke this at any point of time

Comment: I can see the metadata from the URL; that is fine. About debugging I do not have access to create Application Insight. Did you find anything suspicious from the files that I shared?

Comment: Follow **Placing the desired relying party policy in "Development" mode** section at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%205.md it will help you to enable developer mode and easy to debug. No need of Application Insights and that is pretty stright

Comment: Join here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66380/b2c-saml-rp I can discuss with you

Comment: I am seeing this message in chat room "Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information. You have requested talk privileges in this room; please be patient while the room owner processes your request."

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with B2C [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).

Your logon page will now have two buttons:

- Normal B2C auth
- SAML auth to third party

Comment: Thanks for this peice of information but what would be the link on my application clicking on which my b2c tanent sends saml to third party. I mean what kind of value the link will have?

Comment: Read the documentation and you'll see it described. You configure the button in the XML. When you click it, it kicks off an authentication flow.